# Graph homomorphism, but edges can be mapped to paths

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Let $G$ and $H$ be graphs. Is there a name for a function $f$ which

1. Maps each vertex $x$ of $G$ to a vertex $f(x)$ of $H$
2. Maps each edge $e \in E(G)$ with endpoints $x$ and $y$ to a path $f(e)$ between $f(x)$ and $f(y)$

In other words, $f$ is like a graph homomorphism, but edges can be mapped to any path with the right endpoints.

Comment: Yeah, I've missed that you want edges-to-paths mapping. This is a weird requirement to be honest. It seems like this is the same as graph homomorphism $G\to P(H)$ where $P(H)$ is the graph with the same vertices as $H$ but there's an edge for each path in $H$.

Comment: @Aryadeva What do you mean what have I tried? I'm writing a proof that uses this and I'm wondering if there's a standard name for this...

Comment: @freakish The idea is that the edges in the graph represent basic transformations between certain states, and paths represent more complex transformations that are composed of several basic transformations. So in this case the right concept of homomorphism should be allowed to reduce what's considered a basic transformation in one graph, to a sequence of basic transformations in another.

Comment: Sorry the comment wasn'r meant for this question but for another one. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor). If you treat the graphs as [categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_(mathematics)), where the objects are vertices, morphisms are paths, and composition is path concatenation, then what you describe is a functor between the graphs.

You also say in the comments:

> The idea is that the edges in the graph represent basic transformations between certain states, and paths represent more complex transformations that are composed of several basic transformations.

This is exactly what categories are used for.

Answer (score 2):

This is a homomorphism from a [subdivision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_(graph_theory)#Subdivision_and_smoothing) of $G$ to $H$.

You probably want the homomorphism to be injective, because otherwise there are almost always uninteresting maps of this type. In the injective case, we more commonly say that there is a subgraph of $H$ which is a subdivision of $G$. (You can see this used, for example, in [Kuratowski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_theorem).)